# What's the difference between .picture{} and .picture img{}?

Tags: css

I'm having difficulties understanding the difference between .pic and .pic img. They behave different in my code:

```
<div class="picture">
                    <img src="picture.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.picture img` selects the `img` child inside the `div` named `.picture`, and `.picture` only grabs the `div` named `.picture`